# Easily open PDF attachments from gnus with pdf-tools?

Tags: gnus, pdf-tools

I seem to remember that I used to be able to press `RET` on a PDF attachment button in a Gnus article and have it open with pdf-tools. It's not working now, when I press `RET` I get prompted to save the PDF somewhere (after which I can use `find-file` to view it with pdf-tools). The prompt says "Save MIME part to:", just like when pressing `o` on the button (which runs `gnus-mime-save-part`). The same thing happens with `E` (`gnus-mime-view-part-internally`), which I also wouldn't expect.

Using either `c` or `K c` (the oddly named `gnus-mime-copy-part` and `gnus-copy-article-part`) *does* open the PDF attachment in a new buffer using pdf-tools, so a simple workaround would be to just use `c` instead of `RET` or `E`. But I really seem to remember that `RET` used to work (but I don't remember when it worked: I stopped using Gnus for a while, I'm probably not on the same versions of Emacs, Gnus and pdf-tools) and I don't know what changed.

Am I misremembering? Did this work at some point? How can I fix it?

I'm using Emacs 28.0.50, Gnus 5.13 and pdf-tools-20200214 from MELPA.

Comment: Omar, take a look at my edited reply below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this on my setup and everything works the way you remember. I pressed `RET` on a pdf attachment from gnus (which runs `gnus-article-press-button`) and it got opened in a pdf-tools buffer.

I'm on GNU Emacs 26.3, Gnus 5.13 and pdf-tools 0.90 - all of them provided by the [Guix package manager](https://guix.gnu.org/).

Let me share with you my pdf-tools config (in case that can be of any help).

```
(use-package pdf-tools
  :when window-system
  :custom (pdf-view-midnight-colors '("#ffffff" . "#000000"))
  :config
  ;; (setq image-scaling-factor 1) ; Emacs 27 needs this
  ;; this is a hack so that I can use docview links in org-mode
  (defalias 'doc-view-goto-page 'pdf-view-goto-page)
  :mode ("\\.pdf\\'" . pdf-view-mode)
  :hook
  ((pdf-view-mode-hook . pdf-view-fit-height-to-window)
   (pdf-view-mode-hook . pdf-links-minor-mode)
   (pdf-view-mode-hook . pdf-annot-minor-mode)
   (pdf-view-mode-hook . pdf-view-auto-slice-minor-mode)
   (pdf-view-mode-hook . (lambda ()
                           (when (eq
                                  (frame-parameter nil 'background-mode)
                                  'dark)
                             (pdf-view-midnight-minor-mode))))))
```

**Edit**: I'm on GNU Emacs 27.1 and I'm facing the same issue that you describe.  I tried to have a look at the git repository to try to understand what happened but I couldn't figure out.  Anyway you can find a possible solution below:

```
(use-package gnus-art
  :commands gnus-mime-button-map
  :bind (:map gnus-mime-button-map
              ("RET" . gnus-mime-copy-part)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I don't think I need it anymore since I've grown accustomed to the default binding of `c` for `gnus-mime-copy-part`.

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/redguardtoo/mastering-emacs-in-one-year-guide/blob/master/gnus-guide-en.org#open-attachment

Quoted from article,

```
Move focus over the attachment and press Enter or M-x gnus-article-press-button.

The variable mailcap-mime-data defines the program to open the attachment.

You can tweak the variable on Windows or macOS.

On Linux, run M-x mailcap-parse-mailcaps to load data from ~/.mailcap into mailcap-mime-data instead of modifying mailcap-mime-data directly.
```

Comment: Are you suggesting I add a line to `~/.mailcap` using `emacsclient` to open PDFs? That sounds like it would work but I'm pretty sure I didn't do that before.

Comment: `mailcap-parse-mailcaps` can parse `~/.mailcap` so Emacs Gnus knows which application should run when opening attachment.